# Deleting featured image in WordPress

Tags: image, wordpress, posts, wordpress-featured-image

When I delete posts or custom posts from the trash, why do
the featured images still exist on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, when you upload a image, you create an "attachment". So if you want do delete it, you must go to attachments section and delete it.

Comment: but it should be deleted automatically once i delete the post that use this attachment image as featured image

Comment: No, it shoudn't. Since you can use it in other posts, if it was deleted automaticaly you could have problems in other posts.